# Semantic similarity to compare two columns in data frames using sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp

i face an issue to pass a function to compare between two column

```
import nltk, string
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=normalize, stop_words='english')

def cosine_sim1(text1, text2):
    tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([text1, text2])
    return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0,1]
```

after i apply the function

```
cosine_sim1('like football', 'football')
```

The results is:
        0.5797386715376657

I face a little issue to pass that function between two column in dataframe to calculate the score. here is a small sample of the data

```
 d = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['my name is', 'i live in', 'i like football'], 'B': ['london is nice city', 'london city', 'football']})
```

i have tried to do like that. However there are some errors appears.

```
def cosine_sim1(text1, text2):
    tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([text1(d['A']), text2(d['B'])])
    return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0,1]
d.apply(cosine_sim1, axis=1)
```

The error is: 
TypeError: ("cosine_sim1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text2'", 'occurred at index 0')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be

```
def cosine_sim1(text1, text2):
    tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([text1, text2])
    return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0,1]
d.apply(lambda x: cosine_sim1(x.A, x.B), axis=1)
```

You are applying function to DataFrame but you are not passing the parameters that you have defined.